# PullToRefreshListView onTouch event is not working for parent activity

Tags: android, android-listview, touch-event, pull-to-refresh

I have implemented PullToRefreshListView in one fragment.Now the activity which contains this fragment has its onTouch event.But if the touch is on PullToRefreshListView , the onTouch event of activity is not being called.How do i call Activity's onTouch if the touch event is not meant for PullToRefreshListView.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: i have tried it event not working onTouch and button onclick  also not working before i have not used pull to refresh library that time it's working after library integration another fragments ontouch and event's not working ..........

Answer (score -1):

`onTouch()` is a callback method that is set via the  `onTouchListener()` to let a `View` listen to touch events. `Activities` and `Fragments` are not `Views`. You will need to set the listener to the corresponding `View`. A good place to do this is on `onCreate()` in the `Activity` and in `onCreateView()` on the `Fragment`.